# Почему возникает такая ошибка, уже не первый раз

Tags: python

Почему возникает такая ошибка, уже не первый раз
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте заменить `n // 2` на `n % 2`

Comment: @Danis Тогда начнёт срабатывать второй `if` - а там сразу бесконечная рекурсия. Сейчас хотя бы третий `if` может работать до значений n около 2000. :)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Также, не связано с вопросом: не стоит писать `if F(n) > 100 and F(n) < 1000: d.append(F(n))`. Проблема в том, что результат `F(n)` не изменится в разных вызовах, но процессор будет делать три раза одинаковую тяжёлую работу. Пишите `result = F(n); if result > 100 and result < 1000: d.append(result)` либо `if (result := F(n)) > 100 and result < 1000: d.append(result)` (python 3.8+). А так да, проблема в том, что для `F(10_000)` вызовет `5_000` рекурсий, а максимальный стек вызовов по умолчанию `2_000`, вроде.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы пишете рекурсивную программу. А грубина рекурсии вещь весьма серьезная и делать ее бесконечной - практически невозможно. Поэтому введены ограничения. В Python максимальная глубина рекурсии по умолчанию -  не помню точно, кажется 1000. Ее можно при необходимости  узнать:

```
import sys
sys.getrecursionlimit()
```

и увеличить:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(...)
```

но это весьма опасное действие.

Хотя практически это бывает очень редко когда надо. Скорее всего у вас ошибка с проверкой окончания рекурсионного "погружения".  Но поскольку вы не удосужились представить как того требуют (и не  зря)  правила сайта ваш код в виде скрипта, а не в виде картинки - предоставляю вам самостоятельно выполнить поиск указанной ошибки.

Небольшая подсказка. Вот в этом фрагменте

```
for n in range (1,10000):
    if ...F(n)<1000
```

подумайте, какие числа могут подаваться в виде n в функцию и какая глубина рекурсии при этом у вас может оказаться.

Comment: А почему sys.setrecursionlimit(...) ----опасно?

Comment: @Maximum, ну как я помню, данные при рекурсии ложатся башенкой, друг на дружку, а при изменении лимита рекурсии она может выполняться бесконечно или очень много раз, что засорит память, потратит время и т.п. вещи

Comment: Если быть корректным в формулировках, то не "башенкой", а в стек. И кстати, не только данные. Вызов функции - это создание ее среды, которая должна иметь доступ к среде вызвавшей ее программы.  Это не "засорение" памяти - но это действительно "выделение" памяти в монопольное использование, т.е пока эта функция на закончит свою работу, память считается занятой. При рекурсии надо внимательно следить за корректностью вызовов. И уметь вовремя останавливаться. Иначе может сложиться ситуация, когда надо продолжить работу, а необходимой памяти уже не осталось.И тогда происходит системное прерывание.